# Php - format double-quoted string from a class

Tags: php, string-formatting, double-quotes

I have a class that build my main navigation. Everything works fine except for the html output i get in the source code. In my class i got something like this:

```
public function getNav(){
   $output = "";
   foreach($nav as $key=>$value){
       $output .= "<li><a href='$value'>$key</a></li>\n";
   }
   return $output;
}
```

Then i show navigation in my template...

```
    <ul class="nav">
    <?php echo $site->getNav(); ?>
    </ul>
```

... and the html source look like this:

```
     <ul id="nav">
           <li><a href='index.php'><span>HOME</span></a></li>
<li><a href='page2.php'><span>PAGE 2</span></a></li>
<li><a href='page3.php'><span>PAGE 3</span></a></li>
     </ul>
```

This is probably irrelevant, i'm just trying to understand if i get this due to the double quoted or what...

Comment: and what's wrong with the output?

Comment: @Dagon: :), the aling of each tag.

Comment: white pace is meaningless in html. if you really care add the spaces or tabs or what every you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This output has nothing to do with the doublequotes(except the linebreak, which you wouldn't have without them).

Are you sure that your template is

```
    <ul class="nav">
    <?php echo $site->getNav(); ?>
    </ul>
```

...and not

```
    <ul class="nav">
          <?php echo $site->getNav(); ?>
    </ul>
```

?
That's the only mysterious thing I see.

Comment: Solved! The tabs causing that, but not because i was adding them in front of <?php echo $site->getNav();?>. Removing the tabs before each tags (p, ul, div...) make it work. Thanks for your help!